# How to create dynamically objects in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this code

```
  <script>
      var demo =angular.module('ExampleApp', ['ngDraggable']);
      demo.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
          $scope.centerAnchor = true;
          $scope.toggleCenterAnchor = function () {$scope.centerAnchor = !$scope.centerAnchor}
          $scope.draggableObjects = [{name:'subject1'}, {name:'subject2'}, {name:'subject3'}];
          $scope.droppedObjects1 = [];
          $scope.droppedObjects2 = [];
          $scope.onDropComplete1=function(data,evt,i){
              console.log(data);
              var index = $scope["droppedObjects"+i].indexOf(data);
              if (index == -1)
                  $scope["droppedObjects"+i].push(data);
          }
          $scope.onDragSuccess1=function(data,evt,i){
              console.log("133","$scope","onDragSuccess1", "", evt);
              var index = $scope["droppedObjects"+i].indexOf(data);
              if (index > -1) {
                  $scope["droppedObjects"+i].splice(index, 1);
              }
          }
        var inArray = function(array, obj) {
            var index = array.indexOf(obj);
        }
      });
      var x = 1;
      demo.$inject = ['$scope'];

      demo.directive("boxCreator", function($compile){
          return{
              restrict: 'A',
              link: function(scope , element){
                  element.bind("click", function(e) {

                      var childNode = $compile('<div ng-drop="true" ng-drop-success="onDropComplete1($data,$event,'+x+')"><span class="title">Drop area #'+x+'</span><div ng-repeat="obj in droppedObjects'+x+'" ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="obj" ng-drag-success="onDragSuccess1($data,$event,x)" ng-center-anchor="{{centerAnchor}}">{{obj.name}}</div></div>')(scope)
                      element.parent().prepend(childNode);
                      x++;
//                      console.log(angular.element('ng-drop'));
                  });
              }
          }
      });
  </script>
```

What I'm  trying to do is to create dynamically objects on click of button instead of this `$scope.droppedObjects1 = [];` and `$scope.droppedObjects2 = [];` kindly help me with this and what are the further changes required in code. I'm new to AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use $parse
var the_string = 'new_scope';

// Get the model
var model = $parse(the_string);

// Assigns a value to it
model.assign($scope, 07);

console.log($scope.new_scope);

Comment: inject parse service in your directive and add this code in click function